Send Notification to Teams Channel Azure DevOps Server 2022
I am trying to add Service Hooks for Microsoft Teams to send notifications on Pull request created to teams Channel. I have tried configuring connector in Teams and then use the URL of WebHooks in Service Hook Subs. But When I try to test it says 400 error.
Any Idea?

We are using Azure DevOps Server (On Premises) Version: Azure DevOps Server 2022.0.1 (AzureDevOpsServer_20231006.1)
